# Intersection of infinite number of maximal ideals in a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain. If $R$ contains an infinite number of distinct maximal ideals, $M_1, M_2, \ldots$, then $\cap_{k=1}^\infty M_k = \{ 0 \}$.

Since $R$ is a PID, I will replace $M_k$ with $(a_k)$ where $a_k$ is the generator of the ideal. A usual thing to do would be to assume there exists $a \in R_{\neq 0}$ such that $a \in \cap_{k=1}^\infty (a_k)$. I was thinking I should find a way to show $a_i \in (a_j)$ where $i \neq j$ for a contradiction, but couldn't find a way there.

Other than that, I looked at the particular example of the maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z$ for inspiration. The maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z$ are $(p)$ where $p$ is any prime integer. If there were a nonzero integer $a$ in the intersection of all these maximal ideals, then it would need to be a product of all the primes, i.e. the generators.

Comment: *Hint:* $a_i | a, \forall i=1,2,3 \cdots$. What can you say from this?

Comment: Hint: Use that any PID is a UFD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily use a sledgehammer, namely that in a noetherian ring any ideal has only finitely many minimal prime ideals containing it. In particular any non-zero ideal is contained in only finitely many maximal ideals, i.e. an infinite intersection of maximal ideals must be zero.

Or you use - as suggested in the comments - the more basic fact, that in an UFD, any non-zero element has finitely many irreducible factors and being contained in a maximal ideal is nothing else but saying that the generator of that maximal ideal is an irreducible factor. Basically this is the same idea as above.

Comment: The maximal ideals are prime ideals in a PID, then by definition the generators $a_i$ are prime. Furthermore in a PID, prime elements are irreducible, thus $a_i$ are irreducible. By definition of a UFD, $a = q_1 \cdot \dots \cdot q_n$ where $q_i$ are irreducible factors. Then by what I think you're saying, $a = a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots$ since $a$ is in all the maximal ideals $(a_i)$, which is a contradiction. Sorry but why do we know $a_i$ must be an irreducible factor of $a$ in its irreducible factorization?

Comment: I think I see, I wrote something somewhat incorrect above. Since $a_i \mid a = q_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot q_n$, by primeness $a_i \mid q_k$ for some $1 \le k \le n$. Thus $a_i v_i = q_k$, since $a_i$ is not unit because it is prime, $v_i$ must be a unit since $q_k$ is irreducible. So the the factorization of $a$ in terms of $a_i$ will be multiplied by some units. I suppose the contradiction in particular comes from dividing $a$ by $a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1}$, which gives a factorization of $a$ that has $n+1$ factors. Thanks for the help.